# Getting a Module Error in AngularJS when adding a controller to UI Router state

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, angular-ui-router

App.js

```
var myApp=angular.module('sampleApp', ['ui.router','MainCtrl', 'NerdCtrl', 
'NerdService', 'GeekCtrl', 'GeekService','ngMaterial']);
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
$stateProvider
    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'views/login.html'

    })
    .state('nerd', {
        url: '/nerd',
        templateUrl: 'views/nerd.html',
        //controller: NerdController
    })
    .state('geek', {
        url: '/geek',
        templateUrl: 'views/geek.html'
    });

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
});
```

I started with an AngularJs boilerplate and tried to use UI Router with it and, I've been stuck on this for a while. When I comment out the line of code shown above, it works fine and no errors come up. However when I add the controller, I get [this module error](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=sampleApp&p1=ReferenceError%3A%20NerdController%20is%20not%20defined%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fjs%2Fapp.js%3A15%3A25%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.invoke%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Flibs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A44%3A390)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Flibs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A42%3A279)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Flibs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A42%3A418%0A%20%20%20%20at%20r%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Flibs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A8%3A7)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Flibs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A42%3A180)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20gb%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Flibs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A46%3A250)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Flibs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A22%3A19)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Uc%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Flibs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A22%3A332)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20we%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Flibs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A1) in the console with "ReferenceError: NerdController is not defined" . I've defined the controller and added the controller dependency and I'm not sure what I need to do. It seems like a simple error that I'm overseeing. Thanks for the help!

Here is the controller file:

```
angular.module('NerdCtrl', []).controller('NerdController', function($scope) 

{
$scope.tagline = 'Nothing beats a pocket protector!';
});
```

Could it be something wrong with my directory structure?

Comment: post your index.html where you have refered .js files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change to :  `controller: "NerdController"`

```
var myApp=angular.module('sampleApp', ['ui.router','MainCtrl', 'NerdCtrl', 
    'NerdService', 'GeekCtrl', 'GeekService','ngMaterial']);
    myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: 'views/login.html'

        })
        .state('nerd', {
            url: '/nerd',
            templateUrl: 'views/nerd.html',
            controller: "NerdController"
        })
        .state('geek', {
            url: '/geek',
            templateUrl: 'views/geek.html'
        });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
    });
```